# Replace string SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string which is in `99999 124 fdsg` format.

I want to replace the first space with `-` and the next space with a non-space.  My expected result will look like this:

```
99999-124fdsg
```

To replace the first char I used this expression:

```
stuff(Product,charindex('',product),1,'-')as trim
```

Because I want to name the new column as trim.  How can I do for the second character?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, that you example with `STUFF` works correctly for the first blank you can just wrap this with `REPLACE`. After `STUFF` there's only the other blank left:

```
replace(stuff(Product,charindex(' ',product),1,'-'),' ','')
```

Working example:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(50) = '99999 124 fdsg';
select replace(stuff(@s,charindex(' ',@s),1,'-'),' ','')
```

The result

```
99999-124fdsg
```

Answer (score 4):

`Charindex` has last parameter `start_location` use it to search for second empty string

Try this

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(50) = '99999 124 fdsg'

SELECT Stuff(Stuff(@str,Charindex(' ',@str),1,'-'),Charindex(' ',@str,Charindex(' ',@str) + 1),1,'')
```

**Result :** `99999-124fdsg`

Comment: I think, there's no need to search for the second blank, because the second blank is the only one after the first operation...

Comment: @Shnugo OP mentioned *the next space with a non-space*. So it may not be the last empty string. If it is last empty string then definitely your answer looks lot better